# TSQL transaction - commit and rollback

Tags: t-sql, transactions

I have two procedure:

```
create procedure P2
as
begin
    print @@trancount
    begin tran

    if 1 = 1
    begin
          print @@trancount
          rollback
    end
    else
    begin
          commit
    end
end
go


create procedure P1
as
begin
    begin tran
        print @@trancount
        exec P2
        print @@trancount
    commit
end
go

exec P1
```

When I call P1 I got:

```
1
1
2
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure P2, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
0
Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure P1, Line 8
The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
```

I expected result like this:

```
1
1
2
1
```

My questions are:

```
1. Why do I got this error?

2. How should I write my procedure to do it good?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your Procedure `P2` executes the `rollback` line, you are rolling back the outer-most transaction. (The one originally created in P1)  This changes the transaction count from the time before `P2` was called, until after it was executed.

If you expect a procedure to affect the transaction count, you could call the procedure in a [Try-Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) to be able to handle the informational message you get back.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx):

```
In stored procedures, ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statements without a savepoint_name
or transaction_name roll back all statements to the outermost BEGIN TRANSACTION.
A ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement in a stored procedure that causes @@TRANCOUNT
to have a different value when the stored procedure completes than the
@@TRANCOUNT value when the stored procedure was called produces an informational
message. This message does not affect subsequent processing.
```

You may also want to look at the article on [nesting transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
alter procedure P2 as 
    begin  
           print @@trancount 
               IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                        BEGIN
                            save tran SAVEPOINT1
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN 
                         begin tran
                        END 
                     if 1 = 1    
                     begin  
                            print @@trancount
                            IF XACT_STATE() <> -1
                            BEGIN
                                rollback tran SAVEPOINT1        
                            END

                     end
                            else
                        begin  
                         commit   
                      end 
            end 
    go 
alter procedure P1 
    as 
    begin
            begin tran
            print @@trancount                                    
            exec P2     
            print @@trancount    
            commit 
    end 
go
 exec P1
```